# How to perform text substitution of new lines using Make functions?

Tags: makefile

I have a `make` variable containing a list of files with one file per line and I'd like to join all of them into a single-line space-separated list.

The following excerpt was a naive attempt to do that, without success.

```
define FILELIST
  src/foo.c
  src/bar.c
  src/frobnicator.c
endef
empty :=
space := $(empty) $(empty)
$(subst \n,$(space),$(FILELIST))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define FILELIST
  src/foo.c
  src/bar.c
  src/frobnicator.c
endef

$(info FILELIST=$(FILELIST))
F1 := $(foreach w, $(FILELIST), $(strip $(w)))
$(info F1=$(F1))
FILELIST := $(strip $(F1))
$(info FILELIST=$(FILELIST))
```

result:

```
FILELIST=  src/foo.c
  src/bar.c
  src/frobnicator.c
F1= src/foo.c src/bar.c src/frobnicator.c
FILELIST=src/foo.c src/bar.c src/frobnicator.c
```